# iOS 7, Microsoft Exchange, Global Address List and Telephone Numbers

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook, iphone, exchange, ios

I am currently trying to work out if it is possible to generate telephone numbers in iOS7 from a global address list on the exchange. It appears to be picking up names however it doesn't appear to be picking up the numbers or saving any details except the name and email address after using the contact for the first time.

Has anyone had any experience with this before?

Thank you.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is best asked at http://apple.stackexchange.com/